# Prevent reload controller in a nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I coding a modular adminpanel and only need load specific data one time.

```
<div id="main" ui-view>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>

    <!-- Start: Content-Wrapper -->
    <section id="content_wrapper">
        <div ui-view="topbar"></div>
        <div ui-view="main"></div>
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Topbar, header and footer should only load one time or an specific event.

I have set my states like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/header.html',
                controller: 'AuthController'
            },
            'sidebar@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/sidebar.html',
                controller: 'AppsController'
            },
            'topbar@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/topbar.html'
            },
            'footer@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/footer.html',
                controller: ''
            },
            'main':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/inicio.html',
                controller: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthController',
        data: {
            title: 'Iniciar Sesión',
            bodyClass: 'external-page sb-l-c sb-r-c',
            requiredLogin: false
        }
    })
    .state('applist', {
        url: '/:AppPermalink',
        views: {
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/header.html',
                controller: 'AuthController'
            },
            'sidebar@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/sidebar.html',
                controller: 'AppsController'
            },
            'topbar@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/topbar.html'
            },
            'footer@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/footer.html',
                controller: ''
            },
            'main':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/appresults.html',
                controller: 'AppController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('appedit', {
        url: '/:AppPermalink/editar/:Itemid',
        views: {
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/header.html',
                controller: 'AuthController'
            },
            'sidebar@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/sidebar.html',
                controller: 'AppsController'
            },
            'topbar@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/topbar.html'
            },
            'footer@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/footer.html',
                controller: ''
            },
            'main':{
                templateUrl: function(stateParams){return '/angular/apps/backend/views/appedit_'+stateParams.AppPermalink+'.html'},
                controller: 'AppController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
```

But when i change the state, the data of the sidebar has been reloaded.

I don't design a good nested views. How can doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! I need use abstract state to define "sidebar", "header", "topbar" and "footer".

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/header.html',
                controller: 'AuthController'
            },
            'sidebar':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/sidebar.html',
                controller: 'AppsController'
            },
            'topbar':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/topbar.html'
            },
            'footer':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/template/footer.html',
                controller: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('root.home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'main@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/inicio.html',
                controller: ''
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthController',
        data: {
            title: 'Iniciar Sesión',
            bodyClass: 'external-page sb-l-c sb-r-c',
            requiredLogin: false
        }
    })
    .state('applist', {
        url: '/:AppPermalink',
    parent: "root",
        views: {
            'main@':{
                templateUrl: '/angular/apps/backend/views/appresults.html',
                controller: 'AppController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
    .state('appedit', {
        url: '/:AppPermalink/editar/:Itemid',
        parent: "root",
        views: {
            'main@':{
                templateUrl: function(stateParams){return '/angular/apps/backend/views/appedit_'+stateParams.AppPermalink+'.html'},
                controller: 'AppController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            bodyClass: '',
            requiredLogin: true
        }
    })
```

Controller only execute one time :)